# Run Startup task for Outlook Add-in without being disabled

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm writing an Add-in for Outlook.

I need to run some start up task like this:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        items = inbox.Items;

        items.ItemAdd +=
            new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    }
```

And maybe more, like initializing Azure services.

But The Add-in is disabled again and again. The cause given is latency of code in startup time.

I know we can force it not disabled.
But ask user to do that is inhuman.

Is there a workaround?
Like, using Web Add-in? I'm using VSTO Add-in.

Or there are other delayed startup callbacks that I can use to do initialize?

Or Use OnTimer call back? But looks giving errors.

Or create a Task in Startup function? Also not very successful.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: first check null for inbox folder and then load items and attached event

Comment: Does it still happen if you remove all code from the Startup callback?

Comment: @user, I think root cause might be Visual Studio debugging itsself bringing the high latency. And I run the project in a OneDrive monitored folder. I tried to publish and with the release version, not seeing automatic disabling any more.

Answer (score 0):

> And maybe more, like initializing Azure services.

The startup event handers are not the best place for such things.

> Is there a workaround? Like, using Web Add-in? I'm using VSTO Add-in.

Web add-ins are not designed for handling incoming emails. They work under the context of currently selected item only.

> Or there are other delayed startup callbacks that I can use to do initialize?

You can use a timer which fires the `Tick` event on the main thread. For example, take a look at the [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

1. Publish the project, use release version won't see the issue.
2. Avoid setup project in OneDrive syncing folder.
3. If you need to debug, debugging can cause high startup latency can make your Add-in disabled. Just force enabling it for a few days during development stage.